# How can a webpage react to Information Bar

Tags: internet-explorer, asp-classic, vbscript, activex

To facilitate uploading on our web application we install/load an ActiveX control on the upload page. People don't realise the information bar is asking them to install this control. How do I set up the page so it instructs /suppors users and helps them install the addon and only proceeds when this is done? I can't find the trigger/http status code that I could check against.

I noticed Microsoft download center shows a page with instructions asking for Windows Genuine Advantage to be installed before proceeding, but I couldn't find it now, and am not aware of other examples I can research.

edit:
Since I found it's possible to use javascript to determine if an object control is installed, see http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t98678-check-to-see-if-active-x-control-is-installed-and-display-instructions-if-needed.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe has an informational bit on the page that installs the latest Flash plug-in. I'd make a small informational bit like what Adobe does for your site. Education is really the best solution for this sort of problem. ...or find a better upload solution. ;)